# Aligning equations with text with alignat

Tags: amsmath, align

I'm trying to add this expression to my work:
[image: Equation example]

I understand that the best way to achieve this is using the `alignat` environment within the `amsmath` package, so I tried the following:

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
m && \text{módulo} && m>0\\
a && \text{multiplicador} && 0<a<m\\
c && \text{constante aditiva} && 0\leq c<m\\
x_0 && \text{valor inicial} && 0\leq x_0 <m
\end{alignat*}
```

But the spacing I'm getting is really weird, I have read the `amsmath` documentation but I can't figure out what's the problem.

This was I'm getting:
[image: My results]

My version is in spanish and I'm using `polyglossia`, but I don't think that's relevant.
Anyway I'm using `xelatex`, and the `book` class.

I also wanted to know if there is a way to write the whole equation in the same environment with the middle text, or do I need to make another math environment for the centered equation at the end.

Comment: actually, looking at what you want to do, `tabular` or `tabbing` is probably a better approach than `alignat`.  `alignat` sets up "columns" this way: <flush right> & <flush left> & <right> & <left> ...`.  it was really designed to align multiple "mini-equations" across a line.  you'd get a better result if you set your lines up (using the longest one as the example) `c\qquad & \text{constante aditiva}\qquad & 0\leq c<m \\` but that's still not wonderful.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The important things to remember are that

- `alignat` doesn't add space between the columns;
- the columns are as many `rl` pairs as specified by the argument.

So, if you want left alignment for the symbols, the descriptions, and the conditions, you should place them after a `&`, with another `&` to separate the pairs:

[image: centered alignment]

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
& m   \quad && \text{módulo}            \quad && m>0\\
& a   \quad && \text{multiplicador}     \quad && 0<a<m\\
& c   \quad && \text{constante aditiva} \quad && 0\leq c<m\\
& x_0 \quad && \text{valor inicial}     \quad && 0\leq x_0 <m
\end{alignat*}
```

By adding `\quad` we separate the columns. It wouldn't be necessary to specify them on all rows, but doing so spares to guess what is the widest entry.

However, this will center the whole alignment. You can get a non centered alignment using `tabular` (and the `array` package):

[image: left alignment]

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{$}l<{$}l>{$}l<{$}@{}}
m   & módulo            & m>0\\
a   & multiplicador     & 0<a<m\\
c   & constante aditiva & 0\leq c<m\\
x_0 & valor inicial     & 0\leq x_0 <m
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Using \quad between the && once is enough to ensure column spacing.

Comment: @vonbrand Yes, but mathematicians love symmetry.