# Remove unnecessary horizontal space from amsmath align between two &

Tags: spacing, amsmath, align

How do you remove unnecessary horizontal space in an amsmath align environment between two &?

Consider:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Version 1:
\begin{align*}
a &= b = d\\ 
bb &= cc = d 
\end{align*}

Version 2:
\begin{align*}
a &= b &= d\\ 
bb &= cc &= d 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I want all the equal signs to line up.  I could do manual spacing, but thats a horrible solution.

I apologize if this a repost: I cannot find this answer anywhere.

Answer (score 13):

you should use the `alignat` environment, which removes the space between the pairs of left and right hand sides. Skipping the left hand side of the second equation gives the result :

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
a &= b &&= d\\ 
bb &= cc &&= d 
\end{alignat*}
```

See for instance [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49014/aligning-equations-with-text-with-alignat) for a more detailed explanation.