# Aligning mathematical inequalities

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I want to align the following at the inequality signs, however it becomes very ugly:

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}                                                                                                                                                          
      \sum\limits_{i=0}^{h-1} k^i &< n &\leq \sum\limits_{i=0}^h k^i \\                                                                                                          
      \frac{k^h-1}{k-1} &< n &\leq \frac{k^{h+1}-1}{k-1} \\                                                                                                                      
      \log_k(k^h-1) - \log_k(k-1) &< \log_k(n) &\leq \log_k(k^{h+1}-1) - \log_k(k-1) \\                                                                                          
      \log_k(k^h-1) &< \log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1) &\leq \log_k(k^{h+1}-1) \\                                                                                                        
      \lceil\log_k(k^h-1)\rceil &< \lceil\log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1)\rceil &\leq \lceil\log_k(k^{h+1}-1)\rceil \\                                                                    
      h < \lceil\log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1)\rceil \leq h+1 \\                                                                                                                        
      h-1 < \lceil\log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1)\rceil - 1 \leq h \\                                                                                                                    
      h-1 < \lceil\log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1) - 1\rceil \leq h \\                                                                                                                    
    \end{alignat*}
```

[image: Result]

1. How can I properly format this?

Comment: your use of `alignat` is incorrect. See for instance, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49014/aligning-equations-with-text-with-alignat

Comment: You don't want to align the inequality signs, trust me. Center everything and leave some more space between lines.

Comment: How do I center everything? Using \begin{center} or \centering seems to have no effect on the alignat?

Comment: Why do you want to this?  If you are deriving a formula, then there should be words and phrases between different parts of the derivation; displaying everything and in particular making one big alignment is no longer appropriate.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus, You can center all the lines by using the `gather*` environment from `amsmath` package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
$
\begin{array}{rcl}
    % First line
    \sum\limits_{i=0}^{h-1} k^i 
    <   
    & n 
    & \leq \sum\limits_{i=0}^h k^i \\[1ex]
    % Second line
    \dfrac{k^h-1}{k-1}  
    <
    & n     
    & \leq  \dfrac{k^{h+1}-1}{k-1} \\[2ex]
    % Third line
    \log_k(k^h-1) - \log_k(k-1)
    <   
    & \log_k(n)
    & \leq  \log_k(k^{h+1}-1) - \log_k(k-1) \\[2ex]
    % Fourth line
    \log_k(k^h-1)
    <       
    & \log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1)
    & \leq \log_k(k^{h+1}-1) \\[2ex]
    % Fifth line
    \lceil\log_k(k^h-1)\rceil
    <   
    & \lceil\log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1)\rceil
    & \leq \lceil\log_k(k^{h+1}-1)\rceil \\[2ex]
    % Sixth line
    h
    <       
    & \lceil\log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1)\rceil
    & \leq h + 1 \\[2ex]
    % Seventh line
    h - 1
    <       
    & \lceil\log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1)\rceil - 1
    & \leq h \\[2ex]
    % Eighth line
    h - 1
    <       
    & \lceil\log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1) - 1\rceil
    & \leq h 
\end{array}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! This is really clean!

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus That's exactly what I thought: the middle term in the first three lines is floating in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar, but I would have used `\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}}` because otherwise there is too much space. But then one has to change the first `&` in each row to `{}&' and the second one to `&{}` to give the correct amount of space around the math relations.

Answer (score 11):

I could understand this only if the center column expressions are horizontally centered, but then the first two lines will become unreadable.

Leave some more vertical space than the default between lines and center everything; you want a sequence of inequalities, each a consequence of the preceding line; the reader will understand this and follow without any problems. Aligning the inequality signs introduces unnecessary noise.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\sum_{i=0}^{h-1} k^i < n \leq \sum_{i=0}^h k^i \\[1ex]
%
\frac{k^h-1}{k-1} < n \leq \frac{k^{h+1}-1}{k-1} \\[1ex]
%
\log_k(k^h-1) - \log_k(k-1) < \log_k(n) \leq \log_k(k^{h+1}-1) - \log_k(k-1) \\[2ex]
%
\log_k(k^h-1) < \log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1) \leq \log_k(k^{h+1}-1) \\[2ex]
%
\lceil\log_k(k^h-1)\rceil < \lceil\log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1)\rceil
  \leq \lceil\log_k(k^{h+1}-1)\rceil \\[2ex]
%
h < \lceil\log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1)\rceil \leq h+1 \\[2ex]
%
h-1 < \lceil\log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1)\rceil - 1 \leq h \\[2ex]
h-1 < \lceil\log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1) - 1\rceil \leq h
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Is this what you're looking for?

[image: screenshot]

Note that I have added an extra column of `&`

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}                                                                                                                                                          
    \sum\limits_{i=0}^{h-1} k^i & < n                                       &   & \leq \sum\limits_{i=0}^h k^i         \\                                                                                                          
    \frac{k^h-1}{k-1}           & < n                                       &   & \leq \frac{k^{h+1}-1}{k-1}           \\                                                                                                                      
    \log_k(k^h-1) - \log_k(k-1) & < \log_k(n)                               &   & \leq \log_k(k^{h+1}-1) - \log_k(k-1) \\                                                                                          
    \log_k(k^h-1)               & < \log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1)                 &   & \leq \log_k(k^{h+1}-1)               \\                                                                                                        
    \lceil\log_k(k^h-1)\rceil   & < \lceil\log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1)\rceil     &   & \leq \lceil\log_k(k^{h+1}-1)\rceil   \\                                                                    
    h                           & < \lceil\log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1)\rceil     &   & \leq h+1                             \\                                                                                                                        
    h-1                         & < \lceil\log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1)\rceil - 1 &   & \leq h                               \\                                                                                                                    
    h-1                         & < \lceil\log_k(n) + \log_k(k-1) - 1\rceil &   & \leq h                               \\                                                                                                                    
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a lot better, but can we center the expression between the < and <=

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus there's a question somewhere that has dealt with this before- I'll have a look...

Answer (score 0):

If you are into the quick and easy solution, the use of an array environment is always not the 'best way' but it is a simple way to get things done. Put the entire array in a math environment, and from there put the operators in their own columns. It is fast and efficient for simple workarounds.

That being said, and as mentioned, centering would probably be the best formatting unless clarity is really the prime-goal (as it should be).