# Right-aligning numbered equation

Tags: math-mode, alignat

How do I get the last equation (6.24) to align to the right...?

See my current code below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Posting a copy/pastable version of your code, rather than an image of your code, is what is needed to help resolve your issues.  Welcome to the site.  Ideally, a minimum working example, starting with `\documentclass`, is best, as it does not ask the site users to recreate that which you could conveniently provide.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Instead of posting a picture of your code it would rather be helpful if you posted your code directly

Comment: Can't you just add `&`s until (probably another two or three) the equation is right-aligned?

Comment: @moewe Can you give an answer?

Comment: @egreg Done! Feel free to comment.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to refer to [Difference between align and alignat environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200813/35864) and [egreg's answer here for a primer on `alignat`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49016/35864).

Basically there are alternating right and left aligned columns and you use the `&` to move the terms right one column. You want to move the `s \in \simset{1,\dots,S}` term right, so in the end it should (in total) have as many `&`s before it in the line as the `\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}` from the first line.

Spacing has to be done manually with `alignat`. But you can also use `align`, where we don't have to do the spacing ourselves.

So you probably want

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
  & \sum_{t=1}^T x^{b,t} \leq 1                      &\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  & \sum_{t=1}^T x^{b,t} \cdot MT^b \leq MMC         &\forall t \in \simset{1,\dots,T}\\
  & \sum_{t=1}^T x^{\tilde{b},t} \cdot PT^q \leq MPC &\forall \tilde{b} \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  & \sum_{t=1}^k x^{p,t}  \leq \sum_{t=1}^k x^{j,t}  &\forall (p,j) \in E, \forall k \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  &  x^{b,t} \in\simset{0,1}                         &\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}, \forall t \in \simset{1,\dots,T}\\
  &                                                  &s \in \simset{1,\dots,S}
\end{alignat}
```

where I don't think any further manual spacing is needed.

[image]

With `align`

```
\begin{align}
  & \sum_{t=1}^T x^{b,t} \leq 1                      &\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  & \sum_{t=1}^T x^{b,t} \cdot MT^b \leq MMC         &\forall t \in \simset{1,\dots,T}\\
  & \sum_{t=1}^T x^{\tilde{b},t} \cdot PT^q \leq MPC &\forall \tilde{b} \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  & \sum_{t=1}^k x^{p,t}  \leq \sum_{t=1}^k x^{j,t}  &\forall (p,j) \in E, \forall k \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  &  x^{b,t} \in\simset{0,1}                         &\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}, \forall t \in \simset{1,\dots,T}\\
  &                                                  &s \in \simset{1,\dots,S}
\end{align}
```

---

Or maybe you even want alignment at the first relation sign

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
  \sum_{t=1}^T x^{b,t}                     &\leq 1
    &\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  \sum_{t=1}^T x^{b,t} \cdot MT^b          &\leq MMC
    &\forall t \in \simset{1,\dots,T}\\
  \sum_{t=1}^T x^{\tilde{b},t} \cdot PT^q  &\leq MPC
    &\forall \tilde{b} \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  \sum_{t=1}^k x^{p,t}                     &\leq \sum_{t=1}^k x^{j,t}
    &\forall (p,j) \in E, \forall k \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  x^{b,t}                                  &\in\simset{0,1}
    &\quad\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}, \forall t \in \simset{1,\dots,T}\\
                                           &
    &s \in \simset{1,\dots,S}
\end{alignat}
```

Where I found it necessary to insert at least a `\quad` in line (11).

[image]

Or with `align`

```
\begin{align}
  \sum_{t=1}^T x^{b,t}                     &\leq 1
    &\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  \sum_{t=1}^T x^{b,t} \cdot MT^b          &\leq MMC
    &\forall t \in \simset{1,\dots,T}\\
  \sum_{t=1}^T x^{\tilde{b},t} \cdot PT^q  &\leq MPC
    &\forall \tilde{b} \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  \sum_{t=1}^k x^{p,t}                     &\leq \sum_{t=1}^k x^{j,t}
    &\forall (p,j) \in E, \forall k \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  x^{b,t}                                  &\in\simset{0,1}
    &\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}, \forall t \in \simset{1,\dots,T}\\
                                           &
    &s \in \simset{1,\dots,S}
\end{align}
```

The need for manual spacing vanishes here.

Full MWE (including the definition of the mysterious `\simset`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\simset}{\{}{\}}


\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  & \sum_{t=1}^T x^{b,t} \leq 1                      &\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  & \sum_{t=1}^T x^{b,t} \cdot MT^b \leq MMC         &\forall t \in \simset{1,\dots,T}\\
  & \sum_{t=1}^T x^{\tilde{b},t} \cdot PT^q \leq MPC &\forall \tilde{b} \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  & \sum_{t=1}^k x^{p,t}  \leq \sum_{t=1}^k x^{j,t}  &\forall (p,j) \in E, \forall k \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  &  x^{b,t} \in\simset{0,1}                         &\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}, \forall t \in \simset{1,\dots,T}\\
  &                                                  &s \in \simset{1,\dots,S}
\end{alignat}

\begin{align}
  & \sum_{t=1}^T x^{b,t} \leq 1                      &\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  & \sum_{t=1}^T x^{b,t} \cdot MT^b \leq MMC         &\forall t \in \simset{1,\dots,T}\\
  & \sum_{t=1}^T x^{\tilde{b},t} \cdot PT^q \leq MPC &\forall \tilde{b} \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  & \sum_{t=1}^k x^{p,t}  \leq \sum_{t=1}^k x^{j,t}  &\forall (p,j) \in E, \forall k \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  &  x^{b,t} \in\simset{0,1}                         &\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}, \forall t \in \simset{1,\dots,T}\\
  &                                                  &s \in \simset{1,\dots,S}
\end{align}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  \sum_{t=1}^T x^{b,t}                     &\leq 1
    &\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  \sum_{t=1}^T x^{b,t} \cdot MT^b          &\leq MMC
    &\forall t \in \simset{1,\dots,T}\\
  \sum_{t=1}^T x^{\tilde{b},t} \cdot PT^q  &\leq MPC
    &\forall \tilde{b} \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  \sum_{t=1}^k x^{p,t}                     &\leq \sum_{t=1}^k x^{j,t}
    &\forall (p,j) \in E, \forall k \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  x^{b,t}                                  &\in\simset{0,1}
    &\quad\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}, \forall t \in \simset{1,\dots,T}\\
                                           &
    &s \in \simset{1,\dots,S}
\end{alignat}

\begin{align}
  \sum_{t=1}^T x^{b,t}                     &\leq 1
    &\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  \sum_{t=1}^T x^{b,t} \cdot MT^b          &\leq MMC
    &\forall t \in \simset{1,\dots,T}\\
  \sum_{t=1}^T x^{\tilde{b},t} \cdot PT^q  &\leq MPC
    &\forall \tilde{b} \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  \sum_{t=1}^k x^{p,t}                     &\leq \sum_{t=1}^k x^{j,t}
    &\forall (p,j) \in E, \forall k \in \simset{1,\dots,B}\\
  x^{b,t}                                  &\in\simset{0,1}
    &\forall b \in \simset{1,\dots,B}, \forall t \in \simset{1,\dots,T}\\
                                           &
    &s \in \simset{1,\dots,S}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

Well, I'm not retype your code from given picture. This will should be easy to you. MWE below show the principle, how to format it to achieve above picture.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    P\max \sum_1\sum_2\sum_3 \frac{1}{S} x^{b,t} v^b d^t
\end{equation}
s.t.
\begin{align}
    &   \sum_1 a    &   b\in\{1,\dots,B\}               &   \\ 
    &   \sum_1 b    &   \text{longer conditions}        &   \\
    &   \sum_1 c    &   \text{the longest conditions}   &   
\end{align}
    \end{document}
```