# Aligning space characters with non-space characters with alignat

Tags: alignat

I have the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    2^0 &= 1 \pmod{21}, &\qquad 2^4 &\qquad &= 16 \pmod{21},\\
    2^1 &= 2 \pmod{21}, &\qquad 2^5 &= 32   &= 11 \pmod{21},\\
    2^2 &= 4 \pmod{21}, &\qquad 2^6 &= 64   &= 1  \pmod{21}.\\
    2^3 &= 8 \pmod{21}, &\qquad     &\qquad &\qquad
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

but it's producing this:

[image: Bad LaTeX formatting]

How do I get those equals on the right to be lined up?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get an error when compiling your document, not even producing the output. You have too many &s for your 2 alignment points.

Comment: Thank you! So that number after the `alignat` command should be a 4? I'll test that out.

Comment: No, it should be 3: count your `&` characters add 1 and divide that by 2 (rounding up).

Comment: @TeXnician Okay, so it looks like changing it to a 4 got rid of the errors, but still didn't fix the alignment. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Correct, but at least it's compilable now. Are you only interested in an alignat solution?

Comment: @TeXnician Okay, even 3 still has weird alignment. I'll put 3 in the edit.

Comment: @TeXnician nope, any solution will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `alignat` solution, even if I would use an ordinary tabular or array, [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49016/101651).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
2^0 &= 1 \pmod{21},&\qquad  2^4 & &  & = {} &  16    &  \pmod{21},\\
2^1 &= 2 \pmod{21}, &  2^5 &= 32 & & =   & 11  &   \pmod{21},\\
 2^2 &= 4 \pmod{21}, &  2^6 &= 64 & & =  & 1  &  \pmod{21}.\\
2^3 &= 8 \pmod{21},
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What do the double `&&`s do?

Comment: @ProQ They change the left/right alignment, see the link in my answer.

Comment: Shouldn't there be  an odd number of ampersands in each row (twice the number of columns – 1)?

Comment: @Bernard Please correct it! I did it on a hurry and  now I can't, thank you!

Comment: @CarlaTeX: È fatto!

Comment: @Bernard Grazie!

Answer (score 2):

Here, I use a `\tabularCenterstack`, which has column-alignment features similar to `tabular`, while providing math spacing features across tabs, similar to `align`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\TABbinary
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\[\tabularCenterstack{rlrlcrl}{
    2^0 &= 1 \pmod{21}, &\qquad 2^4 &       &=& 16 &\pmod{21},\\
    2^1 &= 2 \pmod{21}, &\qquad 2^5 &= 32   &=& 11 &\pmod{21},\\
    2^2 &= 4 \pmod{21}, &\qquad 2^6 &= 64   &=& 1  &\pmod{21}.\\
    2^3 &= 8 \pmod{21}, &           &       & &    &
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]