# Tabular with "display math" vertical size

Tags: tables

I'm trying to typeset linear programs:

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \text{maximize}\quad   3x + 2y &+ 3x + 2y \\
    \text{subject to}\quad 2x + y  &\leq 18 \\
                           2x + 3y &\leq 42 \qquad\forall x\\
                           3x + y  &\leq 2 \qquad\forall y\\
                           x, y    &\geq 0
\end{align*}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{r>{\(\displaystyle}r<{\)}@{\(\;\)}>{\(\displaystyle}c<{\)}@{\(\;\)}>{\(\displaystyle}l<{\)}>{\(\displaystyle}l<{\)}}
        maximize  &\multicolumn{4}{>{\(\displaystyle}l<{\)}}{3x + 2y + 3x + 2y}\\
        subject to& 2x + y  & \leq & 18 \\
                  & 2x + 3y & \leq & 42 & \forall x\\
                  & 3x + y  & \leq & 2 & \forall y\\
                  & x, y    & \geq & 0  \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`tabular` is easier to get aligned properly, but as you can see, it's more compact than `align`.

I'd like to get the same vertical spacing (or interline) as in display math for tables.
I've found the `\arraystretch` property, but I don't know what value I need to put.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alignments increase the line spacing by the amount  `1\jot` so

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \text{maximize}\quad   3x + 2y &+ 3x + 2y \\
    \text{subject to}\quad 2x + y  &\leq 18 \\
                           2x + 3y &\leq 42 \qquad\forall x\\
                           3x + y  &\leq 2 \qquad\forall y\\
                           x, y    &\geq 0
\end{align*}

\begin{center}

\openup\jot
\setbox\strutbox\hbox{\vrule height.7\baselineskip depth.3\baselineskip width 0pt}

    \begin{tabular}{r>{\(\displaystyle}r<{\)}@{\(\;\)}>{\(\displaystyle}c<{\)}@{\(\;\)}>{\(\displaystyle}l<{\)}>{\(\displaystyle}l<{\)}}
        maximize  &\multicolumn{4}{>{\(\displaystyle}l<{\)}}{3x + 2y + 3x + 2y}\\
        subject to& 2x + y  & \leq & 18 \\
                  & 2x + 3y & \leq & 42 & \forall x\\
                  & 3x + y  & \leq & 2 & \forall y\\
                  & x, y    & \geq & 0  \\
    \end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest looking into using `alignat*` (the `*` suppresses the numbering).
One writes this as `\begin{alignat*}{ncols}`, where `ncols` is the number of columns you wish to align.

See Sections 3.3 to 3.7 in the [`amsmath` documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf). You can also read about it on TeX.SE questions, for example in an `egreg` answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49014/aligning-equations-with-text-with-alignat).

I'm far from an expert, so can't really advise much. I find it takes a bit of playing with to get the correct justification (right/left) and positioning, but once it's right it does look good!
Maybe someone who is better with LaTeX will post a similar, but more embellished, version of this solution...

Comment: I should have mention that I've already try it. I prefer the tabular because I can just wrap it in an environment and then I don't have a bunch of && or &&& in my code.

Comment: Personally I think the `alignat*` solution (see @Bernard) is much more elegant. Your document, your choice! :)

Comment: @Bernard also mention the `optidef` package that I didn't know, and that I will probably use ;)

Answer (score 3):

You have a dedicated package (`optidef`) for optimisation problems. You also can easily align it with the `alignat*` environment. Here are both solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
     & \text{maximize} & \quad 3x + 2y &+ 3x + 2y \\
    & \text{subject to} & 2x + y &\leq 18 \\
       & & 2x + 3y &\leq 42 & & \forall x\\
         & & 3x + y &\leq 2 & & \forall y\\
          & & x, y &\geq 0
\end{alignat*}

\begin{maxi*}
  {}{3x + 2y + 3x + 2y}{}{}
\addConstraint{2x + y }{\leq 18}
\addConstraint{2x +3y }{\leq 42}{\qquad\forall x}
\addConstraint{3x + y }{\leq 2}{\qquad\forall y}
\addConstraint{x, y }{\geq 0}
\end{maxi*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to me to be the best answer +1 (my humble opinion!)

Comment: Thank you for your kind appreciation!

Comment: I will probably use `optidef` (that I didn't knew), so thank you! But I can't accept it, as it doesn't directly answer my question.